# what is needed ONLY for bootstrap's twipsy? (class/id that should be included from bootstrap.css?)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I've included bootstrap-twipsy.js 1.3.0 and copied twipsy's css from bootstrap.css on my site. But the twipsy's effect won't work . When I include the bootstrap.css, twipsy work fine. I just need the twipsy's css, not bootstrap's css. Here's the css:

```
.twipsy {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 1000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.twipsy.fade.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.twipsy.above .twipsy-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
}
.twipsy.left .twipsy-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #000000;
}
.twipsy.below .twipsy-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}
.twipsy.right .twipsy-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000000;
}
.twipsy-inner {
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.twipsy-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

and the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FArIZzX77/4Fz5T/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed in some ways the most important CSS property the show/hide part using the opacity

```
.fade {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}​
```

Working fiddle with this CSS added: http://jsfiddle.net/4Fz5T/1/

When you move mouse in, the Tool-tip gets prepended to body and it gets class="twipsy fade in" The in gets removed on the hide function of the tool-tip making it invisible (opacity=0). Please note that its not removing the element from DOM.